# Why isn't my asp button (input type="submit") reacting to my css class?

Tags: html, css

The code below is what i have so far for the configuration of my css button and all it displays right now is normal button.  However, it does work if I would switch to id instead of class.

```
.phasesButton [type=submit]
{
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:125px;
  height:31px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0, .7);
  text-align:center;
  line-height:31px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top:30px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is my html

```
 <div id="phaseOne" class="frmPhaseOne">
    <table width="95%">
    .
    .
    .
    </table>
    <asp:Button ID="btnPhaseOne" class="phasesButton " runat="server" Text="Submit"/>
</div>
```

Even if I place the button outside the div or putting `input[type=submit]` instead, it still would not work.

Comment: Set the CSS class using the CssClass attribute instead.

Comment: @KingKing I believe quotes are not necessary if there are no special characters in the attribute value. Though it doesn't hurt to add them either.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes, I'm used to add quotes because it is a very good practice, not using quotes are some kind of bad practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space:

```
.phasesButton[type=submit]
```

White space is a descendant selector, that is, the selector:

```
.phasesButton [type=submit]
```

Would look for elements which match `[type=submit]` inside of a `.phaseButton`.

[**Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)

Answer (score 1):

First remove the space between css selectors. 
Second the `type=submit` would not work. change it to `type=button`

change **`.phasesButton [type=submit]`** to **`.phasesButton[type=button]`**

**Explanation:**

1. **`.phasesButton[type=button]`** this two are selector for same element so should not be separated.
2. When you add a tag `asp:button` in your webform, the asp.net will render an `input type="button"` for you and when you click this button, it will submit a post to the same page (this is called `postback`) and will processing the life cycle and asp.net event associated with this button. The same is valid for every server control such as `TextBoxes` (render `input type='text'`), `Panels` (renders divs), `Checkboxes` (render `input type='checkbox'`), `Labels` (render `spans`) etc...

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306677/different-betwen-button-and-aspbutton-onclick/14306741#14306741)

Comment: Well, you could just say that `asp:button` renders to `type=button` without copying half of [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14306741/1331430).