# View modal refresh page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

when I view modal in bootstrap using asp.net button the page is refreshing I want to avoid refreshing the page and call server-side event

I tried to stop the refreshing by the below code but it is refreshing twice then stops refreshing

I tried to use just input but not calling the event

```
  g.generator();
         myCode = g.code;

        long PhoneNumber = long.Parse(PhoneNumberTextBox.Text);


        const string YourAccessKey = ""; // your access key here
        Client client = Client.CreateDefault(YourAccessKey);
        long Msisdn = PhoneNumber; // your phone number here
        MessageBird.Objects.Message message =
        client.SendMessage("HealthBook", myCode, new[] { Msisdn });
        SubmitButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return CheckStatus();");


 <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" CssClass="btn btn-info"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" 
                    runat="server" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" Text="Submit" />   

 <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="Div1">
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Veryfication Code:</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:TextBox ID="verificationCodeTextBox" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" OnTextChanged="verificationCodeTextBox_TextChanged" type="number" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <asp:Button ID="VerifyButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="VerifyButton_Click" Text="Verify" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please check the image attached for the cod

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference betwen button and asp:button onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306677/difference-betwen-button-and-aspbutton-onclick)